# How to find the limits of integration of this double integral using Iverson Brackets?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm looking at the approach laid out [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/355396/63847), and have some steps about how to get the limits of integration using Iverson brackets.

I want to find

$$\int \int f(x,y)\ dy\ dx$$

where

$$x \geq 0$$
$$y \geq 0$$
$$x+y \leq 1$$

I can write the regions out as:

$$\int \int [0 \leq x][0 \leq y][x+y \leq 1] f(x,y)\ dy\ dx$$

$$\int \int [0 \leq x][0 \leq y][y \leq 1-x] f(x,y)\ dy\ dx$$

and my grouping the latter two terms using [p and q] = [p][q]

$$\int \int [0 \leq x][0 \leq y \leq 1-x] f(x,y)\ dy\ dx$$

How do I proceed from here to get the final limits which are $[0 \leq x \leq 1]$ and $[0 \leq y \leq 1-x]$?

I understand that this is a lot of writing for something that's seemingly trivially observable, but I'm trying to generate a well-defined procedural approach to finding the limits of integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked post writes about "factoring the Iverson bracket. This is your next step, we have 
$$ [0\le y \le 1-x] = [0 \le y \le 1-x][0 \le 1-x] = [0 \le y \le 1-x][x \le 1] $$
Hence, multiplying with $[0\le x]$
$$ [0 \le x][0 \le y \le 1-x] = [0\le x \le 1][0 \le y \le 1-x]$$
Why does this work: The point is that $[x+y≤1]$ gives an upper bound for both $x$ and $y$. We have $[0≤y][y≤1−x]$, this equals $[0≤y≤1−x]$ which contains an implicit upper bound on $x$, namely $[0≤1−x]$. You have to extract all "subsets" to get the implicit bounds.

Comment: So the factoring step - I'm not sure I understand how exactly the factoring occurs. It seems like we go from [p and q] = [p and q][subset of p and q]...  Could you be a bit more rigorous about the factoring step?

Comment: The point is that $[x+y\le 1]$ gives an upper bound for both $x$ and $y$. We have $[0 \le y][y \le 1-x]$. This equals $[0\le y \le 1-x]$ which contains an implicit upper bound on $x$, namely $[0 \le 1-x]$. You have to extract all "subsets" to get the implicit bounds.

Comment: Awesome - much better. It would be great if you could incorporate some of the stuff in that comment to the original solution for posterity. Thank you!